# Sending private messages Discord-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

help me with discord-api. Sending private messages to the user who just logged on to the server. I have the following code:

```
    const robot = new Discord.Client();
    robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
    { 
      gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").sendMessage(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello guys");
    });
```

Added the following code:

```
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
        { 
          gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").sendMessage(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello guys");
 gMembAdd.mentions.users.first().sendMessage("Test");
        });
```

I received an error message. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you shouldn't use `.sendMessage()` as it was deprecated in newer versions. You need to use `.send()`.
When you subscribing to `guildMemberAdd` you will recieve a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), from there you can directly send a message:

```
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) => {
    gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").send(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello guys");
    gMembAdd.send("Test");
});
```

This should send a message directly to the member that joined.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any error? If so show the error you're getting.

Comment: in the channel writes and in private is not present

Comment: There are no errors. The channel writes in a private message is not present

Comment: Then there must be errors in console. Check the console for any errors. Does the user have private messages enabled on that guild?